# SQL - Can I use a CASE Statement to left join the same table based on different criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, left-join

I have a stored proc that is using a LEFT JOIN to select a key from it. This proc is used by two different applications that have different criteria for when this key should be selected.

I'm getting a syntax error on this. The first statement should be used as a LEFT JOIN if the row was created 60 days in advance based on the @IsCheckDateRequired field.

```
The correlation name 't' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause
```

If the @IsCheckDateRequiredField is not necessary, I just want to left join the table on the keys.

```
SELECT          
        t.PrimaryKey

FROM    dbo.WTable w 

LEFT JOIN dbo.Table t
        on t.PrimaryKey = w.PrimaryKey
        and datediff(day, t.CreatedDate, GETUTCDATE()) > 60 
        and @IsCheckDateRequired = 1
        
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table t
        on t.PrimaryKey = w.PrimaryKey
```

Is this possible to do in the same proc? My SELECT statement above is attempting to select t.Primary key and is complaining because I've left joined it on the same name twice.

I'm kind of new to SQL as well and am still learning best practices, so **should** this even be what I'm trying to do or am I way off base here?

Any advice would help for sure!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your `JOIN` or `ON` clause. it's *literally* telling you the problem. You reference the table `Table` twice and alias it `t` both times; the second reference needs a different alias.

Comment: @Larnu edited for clarity, I have my SELECT Statement above trying to grab the t.PrimaryKey.

Comment: But you still have two objects aliased as `t` in the same `FROM`. Again, that's not allowed.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN dbo.Table t on t.PrimaryKey = w.PrimaryKey` should have a different alias, like `LEFT JOIN dbo.Table x on x.PrimaryKey = w.PrimaryKey` or whatever alias you want to.

Comment: ahh! I figured it out, I used the different aliases and then used a CASE Statement in my select based on and @IsCheckDateRequired. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on helping my with my approach.

It's not allowed to do the same alias on the left join. So instead of having the logic be in the LEFT JOIN Statements, I was able to put it in my select.

```
SELECT          
        CASE @IsAutoRenewalRun
            when 1 then t.PrimaryKey
            when 0 then t2.PrimaryKey
        END
            as PrimaryKey

FROM    dbo.WTable w 

LEFT JOIN dbo.Table t
        on t.PrimaryKey = w.PrimaryKey
        and datediff(day, t.CreatedDate, GETUTCDATE()) > 60 
        and @IsCheckDateRequired = 1
        
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table t2
        on t2.PrimaryKey = w.PrimaryKey
```